# Error trying to update stock with trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb

I have bascially 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
    id_product BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    code VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    stock INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_SALES (
    id_product_sale BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    QUANTITY INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    product_id BIGINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(id_product)
);
```

And a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateStock
AFTER INSERT
ON PRODUCT_SALES
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE PRODUCTS
    SET PRODUCTS.stock = PRODUCTS.stock - PRODUCT_SALES.quantity
    WHERE PRODUCTS.id_product = PRODUCT_SALES.product_id
```

I want to update the stock of X product when someone makes an instert in *product_sales* table, but i get the following error when inserting a row in my *product_sales* table

> Unknown column 'PRODUCT_SALES.product_id' in 'where clause'

I'm useing ***MariaDB*** Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.12-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64).

I've made a [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9tGYCAYyTNhVhwoa1RR1ab/0).

Thanks in advance, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the reference `PRODUCT_SALES.` for columns inside the trigger.

In the code, once you get passed `FOR EACH ROW` you must reference the new value with `NEW.`

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateStock
AFTER INSERT
ON PRODUCT_SALES
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE PRODUCTS
    SET PRODUCTS.stock = PRODUCTS.stock - NEW.quantity
    WHERE PRODUCTS.id_product = NEW.product_id;
```